# Why is no object being rendered from my code using WebGL and three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

This is my first attempt at using WebGL using three.js, and the 
code given below should show a blue cube in a webpage, but it shows a blank page.
I've actually copied this code, and it's exactly the same as the original, but it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me with this, please?

```js
(function ($) {
  // shim layer with setTimeout fallback
  window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return (
      window.requestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
      }
    );
  })();

  $.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded",
    function () {
      var body = $.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(),
        scene = new THREE.Scene(),
        angle = 45,
        aspect = 300 / 300,
        near = 0.1,
        far = 10000,
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(angle, aspect, near, far),
        cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry(100, 100, 100),
        // cube = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100),
        mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial(
          new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff})
        ),
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cube, mat);

      scene.add(mesh);

      scene.add(camera);

      camera.position.z = 300;

      renderer.setSize(300, 300);

      body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

      update();

      function render() {
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
      }

      function update() {
        render();
        requestAnimFrame(update);
      }
    },
    false
  );
})(document);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js" integrity="sha512-dLxUelApnYxpLt6K2iomGngnHO83iUvZytA3YjDUCjT0HDOHKXnVYdf3hU4JjM8uEhxf9nD1/ey98U3t2vZ0qQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: When i add related script tags, and replace `CubeGeometry` with `BoxGeometry`, i get a blue square. Disclaimer: I have no idea about `three.js`, i just read the error message, and looked at docs for five seconds.

Comment: @ASDFGerte You mean adding script tags in an HTML file, right! I already did that. Also, it still doesn't work with `BoxGeometry` either.

Comment: I turned your code into a snippet. As-is (your code, no edits), it throws an error. Comment the `cube = new THREE.CubeGeometry /*...*/` line and uncomment the one i put below, and you'll get a blue square, when you press run.

Comment: I can confirm what @ASDFGerte says. What you call 'CubeGeometry'  does not exist. It is called 'BoxGeometry'.

Comment: @Ethan Hermsey thanks for letting me know. I was watching a video from 2013, and I guess that method was deprecated or removed.

Comment: You can always check on https://threejs.org/docs/